# Google AdSense testing code not displaying test ads on my live website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, admob, adsense

I am trying to implement exactly what was given from Google on what I should be implementing - https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/4599514?hl=en 
I cannot seem to figure out why not a single test ad is rendering on my test page. My website is currently going through the approval process (**Getting your site ready to show ads**) and is not approved yet but in the criteria Google wants you to place all the code on the pages that you want ads displayed on. I simply won't place dynamic generated ads on my page if I have no idea how they look beforehand. I have also tried the fixed size ads and they do not show up when the attribute "test" is added in to the code.
Here is my code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script async custom-element="amp-auto-ads"
        src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-auto-ads-0.1.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>AdSense ad 2</h2>
<amp-auto-ads type="adsense" data-ad-client="MYID" google_adtest = on;></amp-auto-ads>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit 1: For awareness... I check the network files being requested when the page loads and I get a 200 for that amp-auto-ads. It loads in roughly 16.7KB of data

Comment: Have you tried contacting google support? I've had my fair share of problems where I followed the tutorials, added all the proper scripts, etc. But it still wasn't working. Google support pointed me in the right direction when I showed them my test page.
https://support.google.com/adsense/contact/publisher_support

Comment: @JoeL that link doesn't work. Its funny I would have tried to reach out to them but their login portal has no information WHATSOEVER about how to reach out for help. Every other one of their services has an email to contact if you have questions or live support chat. The process was guided up until I input my PIN I received to my address and from then on out I have been just navigating through every link and trying to fill out all the information I can because I don't know what to do next...

Comment: I just tried the link. If I'm logged into google, it works. I'm not logged into my account, it does not work. I know it's a silly question, but were you logged in?

Comment: @JoeL ya it shows my account in the top right that I'm signed in to as signed in. I have another account listed as well that I'm not signed in to. I also tried signing in and out of the account that I have Google AdSense registered for and it still is giving a 'not found' error :/

Answer (score 0):

I know I probably should have just added a comment and the situation might be very different in your case. But for me, the ads showed up on my Safari but not Chrome, because I have AdBlocker on Chrome extension. Just disable that, and my ads show up again.